# I have an issue with Audio on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I've a problem with Audio in Windows 10.
I'd a PC with W8 and I upgraded it to W10. Anyway, My audio doesn't work. Here my PC configuration.

[image]

[image]

Why my audio doesn't work? I tried with headphones too and It doesn't work.
Any help?

Comment: Open Device Manager and see if the audio drivers are installed. And try running the Windows 10 audio troubleshooter (type `audio playback problems` in Search)

Comment: Try HP's troubleshooting steps here - [HP Notebook PCs - No Sound or Distorted Sound from Speakers (Windows 10)](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/Compaq-CQ58-200-Notebook-PC-series/5296096/document/c04973149/). See if any of these resolve the issue. If not, update your question with specific details of what is happening.

Comment: I've a Compaq PC

Comment: Yes. HP owns Compaq. If you give the complete model number (CQ58-?????), we can give more specific help.

Comment: Where I can look it?

Comment: PS: I saw Compaq CQ58.

Answer (score -1):

if you can download this https://drp.su/index.htm

offline version, or online if you want.

uninstall all you sound/audio drivers and install it using offline driver pack, or online

**but stay focus and care on unsolicited programs like chrome in Russian language :)**